# Sometimes my project works fine, sometimes it shows following error in the line mentioned in the code below

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);//Program received signal: EXC_BAD_Access"
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Any chance of seeing the stack trace?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 TRY THIS for future problems regarding bad excess or Sigbrt

Comment: @Addicted: Thanks for sharing the link. Was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re accessing bad memory somewhere.  Most probably, you're trying to reference a pointer to an object that's been released already, and the debugger has had to roll back to the bottom of the stack.  Usually, a hint to the real reason for a crash like this will appear just slightly before "Program received signal: EXC_BAD_Access" in the log.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

EXC_BAD_Access means you're overreleasing an object. Run the app using Instruments Object Alloc with Zombie detection enabled to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Your application going to crash that's why you are getting error at this point,

you can check where application going to crash by selecting iOs Simulator 4.3 and lower version.

This may help you to debug the problem.

iOS 5.0 and later never tell where is the issue for that you must have to run you app in lower version then 5.0.